# Converting Array of String in a particular JSON Format using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am having a javascript array in this particular format:

```
var arr  = 
  ["header1",       //section header
   false,           //subsection, no
   "1240","1243",   //assets
   true,"1",        //subsection, yes = 1
   "1344","1136",   //assets
   true,"1",        //subsection, yes = 1
   "1347",          //assets
   "header2",       //section header
   false,           //subsection, no
   "1130"];         //assets
```

The above array is having a sequence:

1) The array with "header" is the section value.

2) "false" in the array indicates that this section is not having any subsection. So in JSON the sub value is null.

3) Followed by false are all the assets value for the sections.

4) "true" indicates that this section is having a subsection. The subsection value in the next value followed by "true". In my example it is 1. Following it are all assets values for that subsection.

5) When the next array value with string "header" is encountered. It is start of the next section.

I have to convert it into the format:

```
{
  "templateForm": 
    [{
      "sectionId":"header1",
      "values":[
        {
          "sub":null,
          "assets":[1240,1243]
        },
        {
          "sub":1,
          "assets":[1344,1136]
        },
        {
          "sub":1,
          "assets":[1347]
        }
        ]
    },
    {
      "sectionId":"header2",
      "values":[
        {
          "sub":null,
          "assets":[1130]
        }
        ]
    }]
}
```

I had tried a lot but not able to do it. I tried to create the json format as string but got error at the time of parsing it as javascript object. Please help me to solve this problem.

My incomplete code are as follows:

```
function makeJSON(formItems) {
        var subString1 = "header";
        var strStart = '{"templateForm":[';
        var strSection = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < formItems.length; i++) {
            var isHeader = item.indexOf(subString1) !== -1;
            if(isHeader){
                strSection += '{"sectionId":'+item[i];
                while(item != true || item != false){
                }
            }

            var item = formItems[i] + "";
            console.log(item);
            if (item == "true") {
                var subSectionId = item[++i];
            } else if (item == "false") {
                var subSectionId = null;
            }
        }
        var strEnd = "]}";
        var strFinal = strStart + strSection + strEnd;
        console.log(strFinal);
        var obj = JSON.parse(strFinal);
        console.log(obj);
    }
```

Comment: What code have you tried? Where are you stuck? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Where does the data come ? Its format is pretty bad IMO.

Comment: @NathanP.Can you suggest me a good format

Comment: @Cruiser: I had added the code

Comment: The one you are trying to convert it to seems better to me. The data should come already formatted, but since I don't know how you get it, I cannot tell.

Comment: @NathanP. Actually someone tried to parse an HTML table contents and got the data from the parsed HTML. They pushed the parsed element data and my task it convert it into JSON

Comment: I've just cleaned up your input array, after doing so.  One problem I can see, how do we know when we reach the end of assets..  eg.  `"1347", "header2"`..  how do we know header2 is not an asset, apart from been worded header2?.   One logic might be, if a boolean follows the current item is a header..

Comment: So, the one who is parsing have to provide you the JSON already formatted, this is the best way to go because he can tell which data is what more easily than this twisted logic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a straight forward approach with an object for the single stages of inserting.

```js
var array = ["header1", false, "1240", "1243", true, "1", "1344", "1136", true, "1", "1347", "header2", false, "1130"],
    result = [],
    last = {};

array.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.toString().slice(0, 6) === 'header') {
        last.section = { sectionId: a, values: [] };
        result.push(last.section);
        return;
    }
    if (typeof a === 'boolean') {
        last.sub = { sub: null, assets: [] };
        last.section.values.push(last.sub);
        last.next = a;
        return;
    }
    if (last.next) {
        last.sub.sub = +a;
        last.next = false;
        return;
    }
    last.sub.assets.push(+a);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The format of the data source leaves much to desire for. But if this is what you must work with, then following code can make the conversion:

```js
var arr  = ["header1",false,"1240","1243",true,"1","1344","1136",true,"1","1347", "header2", false, "1130"];

var result = arr.reduce( (acc, val) => {
    if (String(val).indexOf("header") === 0) {
        acc.push({
            sectionId: val,
            values: []
        });
        return acc;
    }
    var last = acc[acc.length-1],
        lastVal = last.values[last.values.length-1];
    if (typeof val === 'boolean') {
        last.values.push({
            sub: val || null,
            assets: []
        })
    } else if (lastVal.sub === true) {
        lastVal.sub = +val;
    } else {
        lastVal.assets.push(+val);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```